# A particular problem to find the rank of $AB $

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A $ be an $m×n$ matrix and $B $ is an $n×p $ matrix,Prove that $AB $ can be written as a sum of $n $ matrices of rank one.

My try-----rank of $AB $ is less or equal than $n $.As rank of $A $ and $B $ both are less or equal  than $n $.So the number of linearly independent colums of $AB $ is at most $n $.Let it be $r $ ie. $r <=n $.We can write $AB $as the sum of matrices $C_i $such that $C_i $has $ith$ column  of $AB $and except this column other columns are $0$ vector.,for $i=1,2,...,n $.Hence I have solved my problem .

But that problem is so easy that I did not expect.Am I correct? Or I missed something that need to be used!

Comment: Something is wrong. The matrix $AB$ has $p$ columns. Suppose $n>p$. Then what does "the $i$-th column of $AB$" mean when $i>p$?

Comment: In this case I need to write $A_i $ matrix has one vector which is the linear combination of previous non zero vectors and other columns  are 0 vector, for $i=p+1,p+2,..., $

Answer (score 0):

I have done it too complicated.$r <=n $.If $r=n$ we are done.If $r <n $,Firstly we write $AB $ as the sum of $r $ matrices each of has rank $1$.At least one of the matrix has more than one nonzeeo column.We separate it to obtain total $n $ matrices each of rank $1$.